# Populate array from out sys_refcursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to call other procedures passing it an array.  Is it possible to populate an  array from a single column of a cursor.  Not the select query below is over simplified.  The actual contains a large number of joins to support specific criteria.  So I want to avoid duplicating the query in code.

```
create or replace TYPE personid_array as table of varchar2(9)

  procedure get_by_name (
    i_name                     in varchar2,
    o_person_cursor           out sys_refcursor,
    o_history_cursor          out sys_refcursor
  )as
  v_personid_array personid_array := personid_array();
  begin

    open o_person_cursor for
      select personid, name, age, height from person
      where name = i_name;

    -- I need to populate v_personid_array with only o_person_cursor.personid
    -- This is wrong
    FETCH o_person_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO v_personid_array;

    get_history_by_personids(v_personid_array, o_history_cursor);

  end get_by_name;
```

Comment: Why aren't you just selecting a single column in you cursor query?

Comment: @AlexPoole Because it's being provided as an out and caller needs all three columns on o_person_cursor

Comment: The caller will get nothing as you're consuming that cursor with your fetch anyway - the ref cursor would be exhausted by the time the caller got to see it. You would have to at least reopen it after consuming it; in which case you might as well use a different query (or skip the cursor and just select directly into the array) to populate the array. But as you don't want to repeat the query, you'll need to loop over it row-by-row and populate the array one element at a time - you can't use a bulk fetch - and then reopen it.

Comment: @AlexPoole I don't mind reopening the cursor.  I know it'll hit the query twice but it'll be favorable to duplicating the query for DRYness.  My issue is most examples of populating an array use a the `for i` syntax as the `i` is needed to index into the array, but cursor loops do not support integer based iteration.  I'm not super familiar with arrays but trying to leverage existing procedure that requires.  So trying to adapt the cursor to an array is my only problem.  I'm probably going to end up with a fetch and an extra local var holding the `i` iterator as a work around.